# How to modify WMV video metadata using C#?

Tags: c#

I want to modify the title and comments of the WMV video files using C#. Is there any any way/library to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the WM SDK is the current tool for the job. I found this article about using it in vb.net which can obviously be easily ported to c# - http://www.smithvoice.com/windowsmedia-attributes

Answer (score 1):

You could use TagLib-Sharp. http://download.banshee.fm/taglib-sharp/

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but... You need to download the *.tar.gz even if you are on Windows. The zip file is missing a number of files